# fgets() skipped

Tags: c, scanf

I am writing a program for school where the user inputs name, hours worked, and hourly wage.

```
int main ()
{
    char name[SIZE];
    char selection = 'Z';
    int hoursWorked = 0,
        counter = 0,
        flag = 1;
    float hourlyRate = 0.0;
    const float otRate = 1.5;
    const int week = 40;

    while (flag == 1)
    {
        system ("cls");
        printf ("\n\tP A Y R O L L  P R O G R A M\n");
        printf ("---------------------------------------------\n");
        printf ("\t(A) - New Payroll Info\n\t(B) - Display Payroll\n\t(C) - Quit\n\t");
        scanf (" %c", &selection);
        selection = toupper (selection);
        switch (selection)
        {
        case 'A':
            system ("cls");
            printf ("Enter Employee Name: ");
            fgets ( name, SIZE, stdin );
            strip_newline( name, 50 );
            printf ("\nEnter Hourly Rate: ");
            scanf ("%f", &hourlyRate);
            printf ("\nEnter Hours Worked This Week: ");
            scanf ("%d", &hoursWorked);
            system ("pause");
            break;
```

SIZE is 50, stdio.h & stdlib.h are included. When I compile and move to the A switch it skips the `fgets()` input and goes straight to the `"Enter Hourly Rate: "` `scanf()`. I have tried changing the order putting the `scanf()`s in front of the `fgets()`, to no avail.

Comment: Read section 12 of [the c-faq](http://c-faq.com/). And, since you're there already, read the other sections too :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `scanf` call left a newline character in the input buffer. Consequently, when the `fgets` call is made, it reads that newline and returns.

As per pmg's comment above, check out the answer to [Question 12.18a](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfinterlace.html) in the C FAQ.

Comment: my answer was to use fflush (stdin) to clear the input buffer

Comment: I would advise against that. `fflush(stdin)` has unspecified behavior... A lot of compilers will interpret it as you are expecting, but some will not, and that can lead to problems down the road. I know portability may not be a concern with a school assignment, but bad habits are formed much more easily than they are eliminated.

I suggest, as an alternative, doing something like this with your scanf's:

Comment: `scanf(" %c%*[^\n]", &selection); assert('\n' == getchar());` The assert is optional of course (but the getchar() is not). I just wanted to be sure I was eating the newline, and not some other character by accident. The %*[^\n] that I added basically says "match everything that is not a newline" ([^\n] pattern) "but do not assign it to any variable" (that's what the * does).

Answer (score 3):

`scanf` probably isn't eating the return at the end of the line, so it's being passed to the first fgets.  Personally, I hate scanf - it's better to use fgets and then parse the line using sscanf.

Comment: But be careful using sscanf on numeric data; its behavior on overflow (e.g., using "%d" with an input value exceeding INT_MAX) is undefined.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin - Oh my, I remember many extremely funny a.s.r quotes above that name. You sir are a legend :)

Comment: Thanks, @Tom.  I'm still around asr, just not that often.